# What do the p-values ​resulting from the SIMPER analysis in R represent?

Tags: r, p-value

I am doing a SIMPER analysis (in R) with the values ​​relating to individuals contacted in different reproductive seasons to see how the surveyed bird community has changed, and which species contribute most to this dissimilarity.
I find everything clear, except the p-values. Do the resulting values ​​of the various "p" tell me whether the contribution of that specific species is significantly relevant in the total dissimilarity between the two monitoring seasons? Or do they indicate something else?
Thanks

I find everything clear, except the p-values. Do the resulting values ​​of the various "p" tell me whether the contribution of that specific species is significantly relevant in the total dissimilarity between the two monitoring seasons? Or do they indicate something else?

Comment: If you need help interpreting results from statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, thanks @MrFlick